# I can run, but I cannot walk - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I can run, but I cannot walk. Sometimes I have insects hiding inside of me. I can be written in many different languages.

Comment: Your riddle is flawed - rot13(Pbzchgre cebtenzf pna jnyx. Frr gur sbyybjvat yvax: uggcf://jjj.trrxfsbetrrxf.bet/enaqbz-jnyx-vzcyrzragngvba-clguba/)

Comment: I don't think so. Gur cebtenz vgfrys qbrf abg qb gur enaqbz jnyx, gur nytbevguz qbrf.

Comment: Gura bar pna nethr gung gur cebtenz qbrf abg pbagnva ohtf, ohg gur nytbevguz qbrf.

Comment: @DavidPostill rot13(`V qvfnterr. Na nytbevguz pna or svar, ohg gur vzcyrzragngvba (nxn. gur cebtenz vgfrys) pna or "ohttrq" (nxn. univat na vzcyrzragngvba synj).`)

Comment: Jryy, gur nytbevguz pna nyfb or vagraqrq gb or qrgrezvavfgvp, ohg n oht znl pnhfr vg gb rkrphgr n enaqbz jnyx. Jbhyqa'g gung gura or gur cebtenz jnyxvat, abg gur nytbevguz?

Comment: is it just me or did everything turn to gibbrish?

Comment: @michaelgriffin Vg'f whfg lbh 

Comment: ah. of course. i should have known.

Comment: @michaelgriffin See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/

Comment: I think it's flawed simply because rot13(N oht vf abg na vafrpg.)

Comment: Also rot13(Jura qrohttvat n cebtenz, lbh pna rkrphgr vg "fgrc ol fgrc" juvpu vf jnyxvat. :))

Comment: @RachelAmbler Lrnu, vafrpg vf sne gbb fcrpvsvp. Lbh pna'g rire fnl gung n cebtenz gung qbrfa'g jbex unf vafrpgf uvqvat va vg. Vg jbhyq fvzcyl or vapbeerpg.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Vs lbh tb nf sne gb fnl "gur nytbevguz jnyxf", gura lbh pna va n fvzvyne irva tb nf sne gb fnl "Gur cebtenz qbrfa'g eha, gur cebprffbe ehaf. Gur cebtenz vf whfg qngn"

Comment: @Cruncher rot13(Jbhyq unir orra orggre nf "N sbez bs vafrpg" be fvzvyne...)

Comment: perhaps "written" above should be rot13 `perngrq`

Comment: What is this gibberish and how do I get to understand it?

Comment: https://rot13.com/

Comment: Wow 10K+ views for this question - didn't expect that! This gave me my first gold medal.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You are

> a computer program. You can be run, as in executed. You may contain bugs, which are insects, and there are plenty of programming languages

Comment: You got it. Very well done!

Comment: The answer is flawed - rot13(Pbzchgre cebtenzf pna jnyx. Frr gur sbyybjvat yvax: uggcf://jjj.trrxfsbetrrxf.bet/enaqbz-jnyx-vzcyrzragngvba-clguba/)

Answer (score 75):

An alternative answer (a bit gross, I am afraid) would be

> You are a **Nose**

You can run but not walk

> Especially in winter

You can have insects hiding inside of you

> EEeeeeew!

Of course, you can be written in many languages

> e.g. the above pun also works in German: "Die Nase läuft"

Comment: You are hilarious!

Comment: I think this is clearly better than the intended answer.

Comment: That was my idea immediately when reading the question. I was surprised it's not the correct answer

Comment: The German is actually the other way around: it walks but does not run.

Answer (score 31):

Another alternative answer could be

> Water

Because

> Water runs through rivers and you certainly run, not walk a bath

As well as

> Many insects live in ponds and waterways

And of course

> Water is called various different things in various languages

Answer (score 22):

I'm going with

> Clock

It runs but does not walk

It also contains many

> ticks (as in tick-tock), terrible insects as well

The last one is a bit of a stretch, but it can have

> Roman numerals
>  Digital or analog
>  Military time
>  And the time varies depending on the part of the world you happen to be in

Not sure each of these are languages, but all (or at least most) languages use this device.

Comment: The "I have insects hiding inside of me" solution was clever!

Comment: Thanks! I wish I was better at these, though.

Answer (score 5):

> You are a person with a GPS using bomb attached to them which will detonate if they move by walking and not running. You run with your mouth open and often inhale live bugs into your lungs. Your issue has been written about people all over the world in different languages.

Comment: This one is really taking the piss. But I approve

Comment: Thanks! It's the first thing which came to my mind.

Answer (score 5):

> a train, I have seen lots of them run but never seen one walk

And of course

> how often have you seen various insects hitching a ride, not to mention the roaches that live in the buffet car

And they run all over the world...

> and of course they have names in most languages... train, zug, train des voyagers, TGV, Shinkansen, trentino verde etc

Answer (score 4):

> A refrigerator?

haha Ive seen some really gross ones that probably did have bugs in them. They do also have a different name in every language.

Comment: I think this answer works as well as the others...

Comment: This was my first thought upon reading the question

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with:

> tap.

I can run, but I cannot walk.

> Taps run, when turned on.

Sometimes I have insects hiding inside of me.

> spiders can certainly hide in them

I can be written in many different languages.

> tap is in English; but there are many other translations; including (but not limited to) faucet for American English

Answer (score 0):

> The answer is that you are CODE.. CODING can be ran with different languages, having bug like insects within its own self.

Comment: This answer (more or less) was already posted and accepted. You're right, though!